# Salesforce DX Test Coverage

Tags: code-coverage, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

Is there a way to retrieve the overall test coverage of an org using Salesforce DX? I understand there is a way to get the coverage for individual classes using the -c flag, but was looking specifically for the entire org's coverage. Is this type of information accessible through the metadata?

Answer (score 2):

It's not included in the apex: test commands, but I found that using a SOQL query and specifying the use of the tooling API works.

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT PercentCovered FROM ApexOrgWideCoverage" --usetoolingapi
```